# Setting report column to YES or NO based on date - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date, case, isnull

I have a query that will create a report (Excel spreadsheet) and now I need to add two columns: "2017 DNR" and "2018 DNR" to the report.  There is a column in the table named DNRDATE (format dd-MON-yy) and if it is NULL, I need both columns to say "NO" in the report.  If there is a DNRDATE, need to check if that date is 2017 or 2018.  If it's 2017, then both columns get a "YES".  If it's 2018, then "2017 DNR" gets a "NO" and 2018 gets a "YES."

Should I use a CASE WHEN for this?  And how would that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN to_char(dnrdate,'YYYY') = '2017' THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END "2017 DNR",
       CASE WHEN to_char(dnrdate,'YYYY') = '2018' THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END "2018 DNR"
FROM ...
```

Do not worry about special logic for `NULL` values.  If `DNRDATE IS NULL`, then both of those expressions will return "NO".

Full Example:

```
WITH test_data (dnrdate) AS ( 
  SELECT to_date('05-JUN-2017','DD-MON-YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT to_date('05-JUN-2018','DD-MON-YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT NULL FROM DUAL )
SELECT dnrdate,
       CASE WHEN to_char(dnrdate,'YYYY') = '2017' THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END "2017 DNR",
       CASE WHEN to_char(dnrdate,'YYYY') = '2018' THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END "2018 DNR"
FROM test_data
```

> ```
> +-----------+----------+----------+
> |  DNRDATE  | 2017 DNR | 2018 DNR |
> +-----------+----------+----------+
> | 05-JUN-17 | YES      | NO       |
> | 05-JUN-18 | NO       | YES      |
> |           | NO       | NO       |
> +-----------+----------+----------+
> ```

Comment: Not quite sure about the logic if the year is below 2017, but `=` should perhaps be a `<=` when comparing the years.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson - we only have 2017 and 2018 data in the table, so that's fine and this worked.  Thank you!